# Functional Dependencies clarification

Tags: sql, functional-dependencies

If I have XY->Z is it true that we can infer that X->Z because:

XY->ZY so

XY->Z and XY->Y

XY->Y can be decomposed to X->Y

and since X->Y we can decompose XY->Z to X->Z

Is this correct?

Comment: You need to be able to apply one of Armstrong's axioms/rules or some rule derived from them to justify each step. Give the rule you use for each step.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on [Armstrong's Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't correct.  It would mean that there can never be a compound key.

Consider X = order number, Y = order item number, and Z = item price.  If your reduction was correct, the order number alone would determine the item price, but in most order systems, there can be multiple items in an order with different item prices.  It makes sense for XY⟶Z, but X⟶Z is fallacious in general.